# adding four Values in two text inputs and and getting the result in a label ,kivy

Tags: python, label, cursor, kivy, textinput

I'm trying to build an app that can calculate the sum of four values in two Textinput.i have this Code:
there are a textinput , the user can enter a number in this textinput , then the user can press "Enter", then the second text input is given, in the second text input the user can enter another value,
If the user presses "Space", he gets the result, the sum of the first value and the second value,

my code:
main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock



Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 200)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass




class BestWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BestWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.counter = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff)

    def add_stuff(self, *args):
        self.textlist = [TextInput()]
        self.textinput = TextInput(focus=True)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value {}'.format(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])


    def addnewtextinput(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + str(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.textlist.append(TextInput())
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

    def getresult(self):

        result = 0
        for i in self.textlist:
            result += int(i.text)
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(result)



    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.textinput.focus and keyboard== 13:  # 32 - Cpace key presssed Ascii
            self.addnewtextinput()
        if self.textinput.focus and keyboard== 32:  # 32 - Cpace key presssed Ascii
            self.getresult()




kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b1 = WindowManager()
        return b1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

main.kv file :

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40

<WindowManager>:
    BestWindow:


<BestWindow>:

    name: "erst"
    grid: grid.__self__
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        # you will control that GridLayout from .py so here it's empty
        GridLayout:
            # set the id to be able to control it from .py file
            id: grid
            cols: 2




        GridLayout:
            spacing: 10
            cols:2

            Button:
                id : test3
                focus: False
                text: "Result!"
                on_press: app.root.current = "therd"

            Label:
                id:label_id
                multiline: True
            BoxLayout:
                id: result_layout
                orientation: "horizontal"
```

now i have to do the following:
**1. the cursor must be** in the first text input . 
**2. when I press "Enter"** the cursor must be in the new text input .
**3. Enter more than one value in each text input**, and use a Komma between the values,
e.g. first textinput: 1,3,2 the second : 3,5,3,5  the result: 4 8 5 5
how can I do it ?
Thank you